# Error in fetching json data from server in android

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to fetch json data from a server and currently displaying that data as it is without parsing, in a textview. The problem is that the data received is always null but when i visit the json url it displays json data. 
When I'm using http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/ as json url it is working.
But when I'm using https://jsonblob.com/api/jsonBlob/56aa6129e4b01190df4c0b87 as json url it isn't . I can't find the reason behind it .It is weird. Any thing that I'm missing ?

Here is my MainActivity

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    final int CONN_TIME = 1000 * 15;
    final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

    TextView txtView;
    String ans;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.screen);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Processing");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
        SyncUserDataAsyncTask s = new SyncUserDataAsyncTask();
        s.execute();
    }

    public class SyncUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,    JSONArray> {

    // User user;

        SyncUserDataAsyncTask() {

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams,
                 CONN_TIME);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONN_TIME);

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(SERVER_ADDRESS);

            JSONArray returnedArray = null;
            try {

                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(post);

                HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                ans = result;
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                if (jArray.length() == 0) {
                    returnedArray = null;
                } else {
                    returnedArray = jArray;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return returnedArray;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray returnedArray) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            // callBack.done(returnedArray);
            //super.onPostExecute(returnedArray);
            txtView.setText(ans);
        }
    }

}
```

here is mainactivity.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.co.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#E55A25" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/screen"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:background="#acacac"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="hello,world" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the 1st link works and the 2nd one doesn't is because the 1st link is an `http` link, whereas the 2nd link is an `https` link. The code is going in the catch block and the exception is

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
```

To solve this issue, take a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https).

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I recommend you to use [`OkHttp`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library for networking. Your async task would be something like this.

```
public class SyncUserDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(SERVER_ADDRESS)
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        txtView.setText(response);
    }
}
```

Add in your `build.gradle`

```
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1"
```

I tested both urls and worked fine

Comment: when I did this app crashed

Comment: What errors do you see??, It worked for me only editing the `AsyncTask` the rest of the code is yours